# How the west was won - Is this a noun phrase?

Tags: grammar, phrases, syntactic-analysis, clauses, noun-phrases

I'm trying to determine what the following types of phrases (in bold within the sentences below) would be called.  I want to say they're noun phrases, but I may be wrong.  To me, these resolve to nouns that can be used as subjects or objects, so that's why I think they might be noun phrases, but they're more complex than examples of noun phrases I am finding on line.

- **How the west was won** is something that they still debate.
- **What it was** was not clear to me then, and wouldn't be for years to come.
- I can show you **how to tie a tie**.
- She had a tendency to promise **that which should never be promised**.

Comment: They’re subordinate clauses – except the last one, which is a noun phrase consisting of a head pronoun (_that_) and a following subordinate clause. You’re right that they can be resolved to (pro)nouns, but that doesn’t make them noun phrases (a phrase with a noun as its head).

Comment: _Noun phrase_ can also be used to refer to the use of a clause or phrase, as subject or object, for instance. The _wh_-clauses in (1-2) are subject NP clauses, and the one in (3) is an object NP clause. Clauses like this are often called "complement clauses". So the answer is that these are noun phrases, and something else as well.

Comment: All those are NPs.  @JanusBahsJacquet would be right if NP were used to mean a phrase with a noun as its head.  But it's not.

Comment: @GregLee It certainly is! Some people may use the term to refer to clauses as well, but that in no way means that the term _noun phrase_ is not used to mean a phrase with a noun as its head – that remains the most basic and uncontroversial definition. I would call examples 1 and 3 zero-head NPs, 2 a fused-head NP, and 4 a NP.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, How can there be "zero-head NPs" if "NP" *means* "phrase with a noun as its head".  This is just doubletalk.

Comment: What @JanusBahsJacquet said -  as written in my post below.

Comment: @GregLee Now that I think about it, I’m not really sure what the difference would be between a zero-head NP and a fused-head NP. I would call 1–3 fused-head NPs. The only difference is that the fused heads (_how_, _why_) differ in that _what_ is by itself nominal, while _how_ is adverbial. When acting as fused heads, they produce the same end result.

Comment: It's a [movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056085/).

Answer (score 2):

> 1. **How the west was won** is something that they still debate.
> 2. **What it was** was not clear to me then, and wouldn't be for years to come.
> 3. I can show you **how to tie a tie**.
> 4. She had a tendency to promise **that which should never be promised**.

There are some grammars which cannot separate out the grammatical relations of a word or phrase from its internal structure. In other words they cannot separate out the job that a word or phrase is doing in a particular sentence, from the question of what type of word or phrase, that phrase is. Subscribers to these sorts of grammars get stuck when pressed on the anomalies that these types of analyses throw up and often start talking about phrases which are 'upstairs noun phrases but downstairs preposition phrases' and things like this. They also denigrate the importance of part of speech categories and the categorisation of phrases, because their grammars have little they can can usefully say about these issues.

For grammars such as these, the strings above are all noun phrases, merely on the basis that they are the subjects or direct objects of the sentences they occur in. Notice that the addition of the label *NP*, or *noun phrase*, to this description tells us absolutely nothing at all. It adds nothing that we didn't already know when we decided it was the subject or object of the sentence, because all the label NP means in such a grammar is *subject or object (of a verb or preposition).* This label "NP" is utterly redundant and completely useless.

However, there are also grammars in which the function *subject*, and the phrase category *noun phrase* are completely separate things. In such grammars a *noun phrase* is a phrase built around a noun or pronoun, whereas *subject* is a grammatical relation telling us about the phrase's position and function in the clause or sentence structure. For such grammars many different types of phrase and clause can occur as subject:

5. **Elephants** like donuts. (Noun phrase as subject)
6. **After Christmas** would be best (Preposition phrase as subject)
7. **Very carefully** is how I wanted you to drive (Adverb phrase as subject)
8. **Smoking cigarettes** is bad for you. (Verb phrase as subject)
9. **For him to do that** would be inconvenient. (Non-finite clause as subject)
10. **That he was continuously late** was a problem for us. (Finite clause as subject)

Such analyses can predict various things about the phrases in bold. So for example, preposition phrases can often be premodified by the specialised adverbs *straight* or *right*, and true to form we can do this with the subject in example (6):

- Right after Christmas would be best.

For grammars such as these, then, the Original Poster's bolded strings in (1-2) are not noun phrases, but finite, subordinate, open interrogative clauses. The string in example (3) is a *non*-finite, subordinate, open interrogative clause. Example (4), however, is indeed a noun phrase where the word *that* (which can be analysed either as a pronoun or a determinative depending on ones grammar) is being modified by  a restrictive relative clause—also known as an *integrated* or *defining* relative clause.

Comment: Doesn’t that just rather beg the question of what the difference is between, say, a finite subordinate clause (acting as subject), and a fused-head NP containing a finite subordinate clause (and acting as subject)? Personally, I can’t see any difference at all, except that the second approach requires a more explicit ‘conversion’ (as it were) to a nominal type in order to function as subject.

Comment: This is a very good answer, which cuts to the core of the problem, but then, alas, comes up with the wrong resolution.  Here is the key: "For such grammars, which have far richer descriptive and predictive power, many different types of phrase and clause can occur as subject:"  I don't know about "predictive power", but are we really after rich descriptive power?  A person who thinks so has missed the point of the Chomskian enterprise.  Humans have limitations arising from their biological evolution.

Comment: @GregLee  I bet ELU’s never-ending stream of questions about paradoxical part-of-speech assignments of particular words is because “regular” people are stuck thinking in old-school dependency grammars not modern constituency grammars: **They have no room for *phrases* in their models!** Any deep understanding of grammar requires recognizing how not mere words but entire ***syntactic constituents*** are fitted together. When your model says a noun must be the subject, then *Carefully herding cats is tiring* misleads them into wrongly thinking *herding* is a noun not the verb it clearly is.

Comment: By the way, Araucaria's analysis of his example 10 is highly original.  Yes, highly.

Comment: @GregLee Quite right. *Richer* is completely the wrong word there. Will edit.

Comment: @GregLee What's wrong with 10? (Or 'original' about it?)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, the structural difference is that a closed subordinate interrogative clause has a verb as a head, whereas the head of a free-relative is the *wh*-word. In addition, free-relatives headed by words other that *what* often need the morpheme *-ever* appended to the *wh*-word, whereas interrogatives have no such requirement --> * *Who is next, please come forward* versus *Who is next has not been established.* There's also a semantic difference, in that a clause represents a proposition, whereas ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... a fused or free relative generally refers to an entity - a thing or person. So in *I don't know who stole the diamond* the thing that's unknown is the proposition which answers the question *Who stole the diamond?*. In contrast *I don't know whoever stole the diamond*, the thing that is not known is a person. In certain instances it can be helpful to see if you can substitue a *whether*-interrogative (because there is no comparable free reative in English. Lastly, off the top of my head, a *wh*-interrogative appearing as subject ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... of a clause with an adjectiveal predicative complement can alternatively appear as an extraposed subject in an extraposition construction. This isn't true of free relatives in standard Englishes: *What it was is unclear to me* --> *It is unclear to me what it was* versus *what bit me was infected* --> * *It was infected what bit me*. Hope I've got all that right, no reference books on me at the moment ... :)

Comment: *Richer* is a perfectly fine word.  Logician/philosopher/empiricist will all understand you, and probably agree.  I am concerned that you don't seem to have any sympathy with Chomsky's goal of discovering not the richness of language, but rather its poverty.

Comment: @GregLee The richness is in terms of the detail of the output, though - not the number of rules. A grammar with a clear distinction between gramatical relations and POS, is bound to be more parsimonious because there is less duplication. The problem with  NP defined by grammatical relations is not only that it is less descriptive of the output, but that it adds an unnecessary layer of description. The *NP*-label is just a vaguer description of the phrase's grammatical relations. That's how it seems to me.

Comment: But @GregLee, what's the matter with my analysis of example (10)?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Do those explanations work?

Comment: @Araucaria Well, yes and no. Those are all fine and dandy, but I still don’t really see the difference in the end between that and seeing all these clause types as having a fused head of whatever nominal typology is appropriate. Your way essentially just skips a step, as far as I can tell, which may well be an advantage, but may also not be (depending on a whole slew of other factors).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, for example, there are all the parallels between closed subordinate finite interrogative clauses and other types of finite interrogative clauses, and indeed finite clauses altogether. We wouldn't want any of those others to be analysed as being noun phrases.  Then there's all the parallels between fused relatives and other types of relative clause constructions. In addition, there's the question of what grammatical relation exactly, in interrogative clauses, the so-called 'head' would be fused with. ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... Lastly there's the fact that we wouldn't want to have a different analysis of interrogatives when they occurred in different environments. So they'd aso need to be NP's in *She asked how the west was won/ She asked what it was/ She asked how to tie a tie*. You'd also need an extra explanation for why interrogatives allow preposition fronting whereas free-relatives do not, etc etc. Basically, Int's are clauses and have clause-like qualities and meanings whereas free-relatives are NP's with NP-like qualities, including having a nominal element as head, not a verb.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But because, for me the most persuasive data is the following let me see if I can persuade you this way: interrogative clauses, like all other clauses in English take third person singular verb agreement --> "What weapons they still have **is** unclear". NP's such as fused relative constructions take either singular or plural agreement depending on their head --> "What weapons they have **are** in safe storage". Does that clinch it, perhaps?

Comment: Hey @Greg , why aren't you helping me out with (10)?

Comment: The subject of 10 is obviously not a finite clause.

Comment: @GregLee Why not? Do you see it as a case of subject dependent inversion?

Comment: Uh, I'm having trouble dealing with your question.  It's obvious.  The subject of #10 is "that he was continuously late",  How can that be a finite clause? It's not a grammatical sentence.

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing that's a CP for you. In the kind of grammar I subscribe to, that's an expanded declarative content clause. The word *that* in this of analysis is just a marker of subordination, and the Head of the clause is still the tensed verb. So in this kind of analysis, subordinate interrogative clauses and declarative clauses are still finite clauses when they have a tensed verb regardless of whether they take a subordinator such as *that* or *whether*. It doesn't matter that they can't stand alone as independent clauses. It's a different analysis, but I don't think it's very novel!

Comment: Actually, for me it's a chomeur, since clauses can bear grammatical relations.  Your example 7 is a root clause with grammatical relation 0, the performative GR.  Your examples 8 and 9 have in subject position clauses with GR 2, the GR of objects.  Everybody's got a theory.